# Add ul within li element

Tags: jquery

I can't for the life of me work out why this is happening.

Here is a fiddle of what I'm seeing:

https://jsfiddle.net/258xsLsp/

Here is the sample HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li id="test1">Magazines</li>
  <li id="test2">Topics</li>
</ul>
```

...and the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("<ul>").appendTo("#test1");
  $("<li>foo</li>").appendTo("#test1");
  $("</ul>").appendTo("#test1");
});
```

...and the output I'm looking for:

```
<ul>
   <li id="test1" data-cat-id="5817">Magazines
      <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="test2" data-cat-id="2000000">Topics</li>
</ul>
```

...yet what I get, is:

```
<ul>
  <li id="test1" data-cat-id="5817">Magazines<ul></ul><li>foo</li></li>
  <li id="test2" data-cat-id="2000000">Topics</li>
</ul>
```

I must be missing something stupid! I've tried both append() and appentTo(), and neither seem to want to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending `<li>foo</li>` to `#test1`. You should append it to `#test1 ul` like following.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("<ul/>").appendTo("#test1");
    $("<li>foo</li>").appendTo("#test1 ul"); // change here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="test1">Magazines</li>
    <li id="test2">Topics</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can go this way:

```
$("<ul>").append("<li>foo</li>").appendTo('#test1')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This example uses `.append()` and not `.appendTo()`

You are appending them both to `#test1` which will put them one after the other.  To next the list item, you can store your `ul` in a variable so you can then append to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var topNode= $('<ul></ul>'); //create and store the ul (not we have not inserted it into the dom yet)
  topNode.append('<li>foo</li>'); //append the inner list item to our stored ul
  $('#test1').append(topNode);  //append the whole thing to the first list item (into the dom)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="test1" data-cat-id="5817">Magazines</li>
  <li id="test2" data-cat-id="2000000">Topics</li>
</ul>
```